# Find all the possible squares in a chessboard excluding selected cells

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I have a slight variation of finding all the squares in a chess board problem.

I know we can find all possible squares from a chess board of size 8x8 
Sum of squares of first 8 numbers 
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 ... 8^2

But if there are some cells which are occupied with pawns we need to exclude all the squares which contains these pawns.

for example consider this below 4x4 matrix

. . . .

. . . .

. x x .

. . . .

Total squares = 30 - {1(4x4) + 4(3x3) + 6(2x2) + 2(1x1) } = 30 - 13 = 17

I thought of solving it using DP but not able to exactly identify how to exclude the forbidden squares.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it in N^3. For every cell (x,y) you need a function that tells if there is a empty square of height = z, z from 0 to n, and with (right, bottom) = (x,y).

Now the problem is how to create this function.

And you can do this with partial sums. for every cell (x,y) save DP[x][y] = nr of pawns in the rectangle (0,0), (x,y). Then you can answer the function in O(1).

Useful links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

Edit #1 (n^2logn):
I think you can squeeze a bit more performance (N^2*log(N)) by doing binary search on the square height in the function discussed above. It works because if for z=10 (means you can put a square of height 10 with (bottom, right) in (x,y)) then it's obvious you can also put a square with z=9,8,7 ...1.

Edit #2 (n^2):
Yes you was right you can do it in n^2 :). Think about the function above, the question is: What is the biggest z (height) for current (x,y) if I know the response for (x-1,y),(x,y-1) and (x-1,y-1)?  So here is the idea: the biggest z for current position = minimum of z from (x-1,y),(x,y-1),(x-1,y-1) + 1;

```
int n,m,dp[100][100],rs;
char a[100][100];

int main() {

    std::cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++) {
            std::cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 'x') continue;
            rs += dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], min(dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j-1])) + 1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << rs << std::endl;

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++) std::cout << dp[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output example:

```
4 4
....
....
.xx.
....
17
1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

Comment: I think this approach works but I was looking for in the range of n^2. Is it possible to calculate this in n^2 ?

Comment: OK finally came up with n^2 solution. Damn it's been a while since I did algo stuff ;)

Comment: @VarunNarisetty Did the algorithm work for you? if you need help let me know

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like this solution works. Let me implement this and give you an update.